# Spring Security 4 and Angular login authentication

Tags: angularjs, spring, authentication

I've a problem with seend good post to login authentication.

This is my security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").access("hasRole('USER')")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login/authentication").successHandler(securityHandler)
            .usernameParameter("s_username").passwordParameter("s_password")
            .and().csrf()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
}
```

Spring controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class AuthController {

   @RequestMapping(value="",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getLoginPage(){
        return "login/layout";
    }
}
```

My login page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link href="resources/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="resources/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/scripts/auth/Auth.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="appAuth">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"  ng-controller="LoginController as login">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form name="form" ng-submit="Login()" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="login.username" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="login.password" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And Angular Controller:

```
    (function (angular) {
    'use strict';
var App = angular.module('appAuth', ['ngRoute'])
App.controller("LoginController", function ($scope, $http, $window) {

   var encode4form = function(data){
        var result="";
        var first = true;
        for(var key in data)
        {
            if(first){
                first=false;
            }
            else{
                result+="&"
            }
            result+=(key + "=" + data[key]);
        }
        return result;
    };

    $scope.Login = function () {
        var mycsrf = $("input[name='_csrf']").val();
        $http(
            {
                url: "/login/authentication",
                method:"POST",
                data: encode4form({
                    s_username: $scope.login.username,
                    s_password: $scope.login.password,
                    _csrf: mycsrf
                }),
                headers:
                {
                    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                }
            }
        );
        //$http({
        //    method: 'POST',
        //    url: 'http://localhost:8080/login/authentication',
        //    data: data,
        //    headers: {
        //        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        //    }

        //$http.post('/login/authentication', loginData), {
        //    headers: {
        //        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="_csrf"]').val(),
        //        //'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        //        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        //    }
        //});
    };

});
})(window.angular);
```

Console log:

2016-02-27 11:11:27 INFO  AuthController:24 - Login
2016-02-27 11:11:31 WARN  PageNotFound:1136 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Access_Denied] in DispatcherServlet (When I click login)

I tried many ways but no way didn't work. When I click login button chrome show error "POST http://localhost:8080/login/authentication 404 (Not Found)". When I change login page to login.jsp (without angular) then works. Why didn't work on angular?